# Add custom component to magento 2 Grid

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

i've successfully create a grid using ui component like this:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="context" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context</argument>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">lime_referral_spg_referral_list_index</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">lime_referral_spg_referral_list_index.lime_referral_spg_referral_list_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">lime_referral_spg_referral_list_index.lime_referral_spg_referral_list_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">lime_referral_spg_referral_list_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="lime_referral_spg_referral_list_grid_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">lime_referral_spg_referral_list_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">customer_referral_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" path="mui/index/render" xsi:type="url"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">customer_referral_id</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="customer_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">lime_referral_spg_referral_list_index.lime_referral_spg_referral_list_index.lime_referral_spg_referral_list_columns.ids</item>
                        </item>
                </argument>
        </exportButton>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="lime_referral_spg_referral_list_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">lime_referral_spg_referral_list_index.lime_referral_spg_referral_list_index.lime_referral_spg_referral_list_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">customer_referral_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="customer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Customer ID</item>
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">SPG/SPB</item>
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="referral_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Referral Customer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="referral_point_received">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Referral Customer Point Received</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Created at</item>
          <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="membership_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Membership</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn class="Lime\Referral\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SpgReferralListActions" name="actions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">customer_referral_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

in my grid there is a membership column, only 2 data will show, which are `Walepay +` and `Walepay regular`, i need to seperate the total of this two record and show it after grid like this:

[image]

the total will also be affected when there is a change in the filter, how can i achieve this?